# Web Worker Import Scripts - Duplicate Script Downloads

Tags: javascript, web-worker, web-performance

I have a web application which uses Web Workers on only a few pages to do some number-crunching off the main thread.  I'm using `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` to determine how many workers to initialize.  **Each** worker needs to import ~20 script files using the `importScripts` function.

Although the functionality is working fine, I'm noticing in Chrome dev tools that the browser is requesting **each** script for **each** worker thread over the network.  The scripts do contain cache-control headers so subsequent loads are quick, but the first load on slower connections is abysmally slow.

For example, on my machine `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` returns 8, so I end up loading 8 x 20 = 160 JS resources...

As CPUs get more concurrent, I assume this problem will get worse over time.  I just checked that my friend's AMD Ryzen CPU was returning 16 making for 320 total script downloads!  I would like find a way to load these scripts only once for all workers regardless of how many workers are being initialized.